# how to prevent "hello+world" converting to "hello world" in mvc action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my url, I have "?msg=hello+world", and in my action, it's converting the value to "hello world"

```
public ActionResult test(string msg) { 
   // msg has a value of "hello world", even tho "hello+world" was passed in
}
```

How can I have my mvc action take it as-is?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code of the action link ?

Comment: can you show us how you create the link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the string to be sent across 'as is' then encode it:

```
var encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("hello+world");//hello%2bworld
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+` in a url means space... you need to urlencode it when you are creating the link.

It should become `?msg=hello%2Bworld`

Answer (score 1):

By no means an expert, but I think you need to be passing it in as a url encoded character, as '+' is used instead of spaces.

```
+ = %2B
```